# Datageneration for Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

I have images that I want to process. First features are extracted from those images and then those features are fed into a neural network for training. I do not have many images though and would like to generate more data.

1) What yields less overfitting: Should I generate more images from the original images and then feed the entire pipeline with them, or should I bring variation into the extracted features and simply train the neural network with more data this way?

The second approach would be computationally cheaper, but yields better results?

2) What techniques are tried and true for generating more data - either more images or the features?

Comment: "Better results" begs the issue: what is "better"?  What *specifically* are you trying to achieve?  As given, is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Prune: Better now?

Comment: Better, but hardly done.  "Overfitting" is determined empirically, after training, for the application you haven't specified.  The second question is a research item -- although I wouldn't vote-to-close on that point alone, since the search parameters aren't readily derived from the topic.

Comment: @Prune: I am not sure what details would be helpful. I am not able to give all the details - for one, because the whole thing is still in development and ever changing and also because it is an industrial application, so I am not sure what details I can disclose. Can you ask some specific questions that answers would help to answer my question?

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work.  That field of discussion has too many variables: it would sound like playing 20 questions, and I don't know all the right ones to ask for various contingencies.  I do know your problem, though, as I'm in a comparable corporate environment.

Comment: You might take this problem to your manager or team lead for advice.  Perhaps you can develop a safe paradigm to discuss where the answers will help your technical problems, without revealing any proprietary plans.  Is there an existing public-domain application you could adapt for this discussion?

Answer (score 0):

Is true that when you don't have enough data the performance of your model can be poor. So you have to try a few things:

1. You can modify the data that you have applying translations, rotations, etc; for example move all the pixel of the image a few pixel to the left. This are operation on images.
2. Also you can generate more images through **generative models**: Restricted Boltzmann Machines, Deep Belief Networks etc.

Also you have a way of determine if you need more training data. In the coordinate axis you draw the score of the training data and validation data. In the **x** axis goes the size of the sets(10% of the all set, 20% of the all set, ...,  90% of the all set) and in the **y** axis is the score. Then you look at the graph. For understand well enough this what i'm saying i strongly recommend the videos of Andrew Ng of Machine Learning(https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) specifically the **Week 6(Advice for Applying Machine Learning)**